# Bubble Sorting In C : garbage value error

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science, bubble-sort

So recently I have been Learning data structures in C . Now let's come to my problem

**Here is my Code of Bubble Sort Algo** :

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *p, int *q) {
  int temp = *p;
  *p = *q;
  *q = temp;
}

int main() {
  int arr[] = {2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 4};  // see below for arr
  int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
  for (int i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
      if (arr[j] < arr[j + 1]) {
        swap(&arr[j], &arr[j + 1]);
      }
    }
  }
  for (int m = 0; m < len; m++) {
    printf("%d\t", arr[m]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

when my array is like : `int arr[]={2,4,1,3,5,2,6,10};`  it's sorting perfectly but when i increase the number of values in `arr` by one , it starts giving garbage value.

ex : `int arr[]={2,4,1,3,5,2,6,10,13};`
output : `int arr[]={2,4,1,3,5,2,6,10};`

Detailed Anwer Highly Appreciated

Comment: Putting int arr[]={2,4,1,3,5,2,6,10,13} as global worked for me

Comment: You will want to visit [Bubble Sort - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) and review the algorithm (and especially the *Optimizing Bubble Sort* section). You algorithm isn't a Bubble Sort, but instead one of the variants.

Comment: Also ask yourself, "Why have I included `conio.h, math.h` and `stdlib.h`?" "What am I using that requires those headers?"

Comment: I know , That was from my last code ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `j=i` and `i=len-1` (which is allowed in the loop over `j`) the check:

```
        if(arr[j]<arr[j+1]){
            swap(&arr[j],&arr[j+1]);
        }
```

goes out of bounds for `arr`. Additionally even for smaller values of `i` the last check is not needed. To fix your code make the loop condition `j < i` instead of `j <= i`.

Comment: yea that worked but can u plz plz explain it by an example , i didn't got my mistake. Again please.

Comment: OK - first thing you need to understand - it is not true the code works for one size of input and does not work with another. Both codes are equally wrong simply one gives (by chance) an output that matches your expected output. Try with your example array `{2, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 4}` and think of what is the check in the if when i is `8` (i.e. `len-1`) and `j=i`. The if will be `if (arr[8] < arr[9])`. But your array has *9* elements, so `arr[9]` is out of bounds for it.

Answer (score 0):

Make you loops like this, and you'll never have "off by one" error:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < len; j++) {
        if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```